# Loop IP in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

we have a tool call  **Mkbrutus.py** file that accepts in the target only one IP address. we need to loop IP like 192.168.x.x/16 and test every IP like 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 ...... and so on

variable for Mkbrutus.py

Mkbrutus.py -t (IP address here)

Loop script for python3

```
import ipaddress
for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16'):
print (ip)
```

so how to make .py file that runs Mkbrutus.py -t (LOOP IP) so can check every IP not just one IP in the target

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your file capable of using arguments you will need to use args

Check out this link in order to pass arguments to your programs.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm